# Which kind of accommodation allows guests to stay overnight?

Tags: accommodation, airbnb, sex, socializing, nomad

### The problem:

I would like to be able to have sex / bring people over to my room while travelling. I know this is not a problem in bigger hotels, but it often is in smaller, more "personal" accommodation like guest houses and Airbnbs.

### Background:

I am a digital nomad which means I am travelling full-time. This entails I don't have a permanent house which I could arrange to my liking and where I could live the way I want.

I usually work from home. I'm a vegetarian travelling in a meat-loving part of the world (Latin America), so typically I cook for myself. My work is part-time and travelling is expensive, so I try to cut costs wherever possible. Given all the above, these are the main things I look for when searching for accommodation:

- solid internet connection
- a desk in my room (or at least in a quiet common area)
- a kitchen where I can cook my meals (or at least a place to make some coffee / snacks)
- affordable price

For these reasons, I typically go for Airbnb, which lets me filter accommodation options to those having a kitchen and a laptop-friendly workspace, and is usually cheaper than hotels. If not available, I wander around the city looking for b&bs / guest houses.
Hotels are usually not a good option, since most of them don't have a kitchen, and many of them don't have a desk in the room. On top of that, popular booking services like booking.com don't offer an easy way to find only accommodation fitting these criteria.

---

Here's a problem: I want to socialise, go out on dates, and bring my dates over to spend the night. And most Airbnb hosts are not ok with that, as aren't some of the guest houses I've been finding offline. They typically say that it's forbidden to bring in strangers, usually because of security reasons.

I don't want to host parties, be loud and disturbing to other guests or the hosts, nor do I want to bring in several strangers every single day. What I want, is that when I meet someone and things are going well, I don't have to say *"sorry, we can't go to my place, it's forbidden"*. In short, I want to have a normal life while on the road.

---

Could you give me some recommendations? Perhaps a different kind of accommodation would be a better choice for me? Maybe there is a good way to approach this topic when talking to hosts about potential visits? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: For how long do you rent a place once you decide to stay somewhere usually?

Comment: @HankyPanky i think 4-7 days on average

Comment: Generally any kind of accommodation allows overnight "guests" as long as your room has capacity (meaning you booked a room for two), and you check them in. The guest doesn't have to check in with you the same day.

Comment: If you rent an Airbnb where you control the entire rental (i.e. a whole apartment or home, not a room in a shared apartment), what's stopping you from bringing a guest? Such Airbnbs usually come with rules about parties (which are disruptive and will be noticed by neighbors) or excessive numbers of guests, not on bringing just one guest.

Comment: Is it possible to always book for two, and inform the host that your partner will join later? assuming that you are not "Barney Stinson" from the tv show "how I met your mother" and you do not get a new date on daily basis.

Comment: Under similar circumstances a few years ago I went for serviced apartments. They're self-contained, equipped and largely anonymous. They're also more expensive than the cheaper offerings from hotels and AirBnB, so they might be out of your budget.

Comment: renting an entire apartment would definitely work, but i'm afraid it might be out of my budget. especially considering i would be paying for it every single night and bringing a guest maybe once a week or two. this would essentially double my accommodation costs.

same goes for always booking a double room, though this option might be cheaper and that's probably what i'll have to do in the end. however, especially when considering airbnb, it would be a bit dishonest to say that my partner will arrive later, and doesn't address hosts' security concerns.

Comment: @Nean Der Thal doesn't airbnb require that you give names and adresses of all guests? That could be hard if you haven't met her yet.

Answer (score 4):

I understand your point. Well, on airbnb you can do that renting a studio by yourself. (not sharing). 
In a hostel or hotel, if you rent a double private room, you also could be able to bring a guest to spend the night because you are paying for two people. The only difference between a hotel and a private studio or home, is that in a hotel you have to register (check in) your guest at the front desk, showing passport if she/he is foreign or a National Id if is a citizent